# Delete All Record of a User From Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-delete, rowdeleting

I am working on a small project in university.I am getting a problem that i want to delete all the record from database of a specific `User`.

I am using a query to get all the record from database.

```
SELECT s.UserName,p.Name,p.Father_Name,s.Email,p.DOB,p.Gender,p.Nationality,p.Domicile,p.CNIC,p.Mobile,p.Address, e.SSC_OM,E.SSC_TM,E.SSC_EB,e.HSSC_OM,e.HSSC_TM,e.HSSC_EB, d.Choices_1,d.Choices_2,d.Choices_3

FROM   Signup s
INNER JOIN Pers_D p ON p.UserName = s.UserName
INNER JOIN Edu_D e on e.UserName = p.UserName
INNER JOIN Dep_S d on d.UserName = e.UserName
WHERE  [d].UserName LIKE '%User_etc%'
```

But cannot delete that `user's` Record.

I have tried :

```
DELETE * FROM Signup WHERE UserName LIKE '%User_etc%'
```

But failed.
Please help me and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to delete records from all the tables in single query. Then query would be something like:

```
DELETE s, p, e, d 
FROM   Signup s
JOIN Pers_D p ON p.UserName = s.UserName
JOIN Edu_D e ON e.UserName = p.UserName
JOIN Dep_S d ON d.UserName = e.UserName
WHERE  d.UserName LIKE '%User_etc%';
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove `*` from your `DELETE` query:

```
DELETE FROM Signup WHERE UserName LIKE '%User_etc%'
```

Answer (score 3):

remove `*` from `query statement`, it should be as below

```
DELETE FROM Signup WHERE UserName LIKE '%User_etc%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Just Remove * from your DELETE query, That will do.

```
DELETE FROM Signup WHERE UserName LIKE '%User_etc%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete * from your query

```
DELETE FROM Signup WHERE UserName LIKE '%User_etc%'
```